# Need some help on geo location plugin

Tags: html, plugins, geolocation

I'm using this https://github.com/remy/html5demos/blob/master/demos/geo.html plug in.

If a user has blocked to share his location or if a user uses this in a un supported browser,
I want to show him a text box.

How can this be done in this code?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    window.getElementById('idOfTextInput').value = message
}
```

There is a if else loop,that will show the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `error` part in this code.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    error('not supported');
}
```

If the Geolocation API is not supported at all (`if (!navigator.geolocation)`), the `error('not supported')` is executed. Furthermore the `getCurrentPosition` method takes two callbacks: `success` and `error`. The `success` callback is called when the location request was successful, the `error` callback is called when it was not.

Comment: :If a user has blocked to share his location or if a user uses this in a un supported browser, i want to show him a text box. How do i do this in that code?

Comment: Is your question "how to display" a text box? Because the other part of that question I have already answered.

Comment: `window.getElementById('idOfTextInput').value = message`

Comment: Dude, I think you should start with a Javascript tutorial. You have all the pointers you need, it's trivial to put it together if you are able to write any code.

Comment: :i put your code in else part,if i enable geo,it is displaying text box but in my case it should not,if a browser does not support means,it should show text box.

Comment: I put it into your question. And I'm not sure what the problem is, your last sentence is somewhat contradictory.